# exportfs must be redone after every boot

Tags: server, mount, nfs

Server N (server 18.04.3 LTS) has an /etc/export file with three simple entries.  Server B (server 18.04.3 LTS) does a straightforward NFS mount command, mount -t nfs N:/exported /nounthook.

If I reboot N, server B gets "access denied" until I manually exportfs -a.  I.e., the exports are not "sticky" across reboots.

What changed lately is that I tweaked DNS on my router so that the systems can find each other by name rather than by a static IP address.  /etc/exports was edited to replace IP addresses by system names.  The static IP addresses themselves were reset to allow the router's DHCP server to assign IP addresses.

When this problem occurs, B can ping N, so it's not an obvious DNS issue.  Also, exportfs could not possibly repair a DNS issue, but does fix the problem until N is rebooted.  (LAN is simple enough that N always gets the same IP address from DHCP server in the router every time.)

Answer (score 0):

Kludged it by replacing names in the export file with the LAN base address/24.

Example:  instead of /a_directory somehost(rw,sync,...),
/a_directory 192.168.1.0/24(rw,sync,...)

This is fine on a home LAN with just one naive user and me, but is not a secure solution in a business network.